# How to update oracle table with long string in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, c#-3.0

I am using bulk copy to insert data from datatable(got data from oracle database) to sql table. So that is good and I do not have any problem whith that. So after this job when data inserted correctly I am trying to update a field of oracle database table with key of above datatable. the schema to my approach shows below.

```
update table1 set column1=1 where id in ( all keys of above datatable)
```

It is not working and oracle do not run that because string literal too long.

how to can I solve that? I do not want to create a temp table in oracle because this service working all time.

Comment: what is the format of  `all keys of above datatable` . Is it another oracle table ? a list of values ? Try to explain the question better, please

Comment: I am select from an oracle database and insert to sql database (oracle table to sql table) and I come back to oracle database to update selected recodes.

Comment: sql you mean mysql or sqlserver ??

Comment: I means Sql server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using a subquery instead, e.g.

```
update table1 set
  column1 = 1
where id in (select key
             from above_datatable
            )
```

Comment: how to can I select keys from datatable inside in clause

Comment: I presumed that you *know* how to identify those "keys". That would probably be a WHERE clause in that subquery.

Comment: I do not have problem to select keys to var or string varible but when I want to use this long string in oracle query that not working .

Comment: That's why I said that you should try with a subquery.

Comment: Dear Littlefoot, I know,I should do a subquery at first time and then run main query. Anyway, I want to know how to can I do that (subquery) . I know one of solution for overcome above problem is TEMP Table. But this query running in a service at the while. However I can do that with multiple update query and divide that more than one query and execute. I want to know can I do that with one query?

Comment: Perhaps by something like `where id in (1000 keys from above datatable) OR id in (another 1000 keys from datatable) OR (yet another 1000 keys)` - i.e. you'd "divide" that large list of keys into smaller parts. In my example, there are 1000 of them as that's the largest number Oracle allows for an IN list.